# Windows 10 Command Prompt rename files overwrites file names instead of prepending

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-rename

I have these files in a folder:

```
aaa.txt
bbb.txt
ccc.txt
```

I want to prepend all the filenames with `1_`, so I try to write this in a Windows command prompt:

```
rename * 1_*
```

Doing so I want to get this result:

```
1_aaa.txt
1_bbb.txt
1_ccc.txt
```

But instead i get this:

```
1_a.txt
1_b.txt
1_c.txt
```

Instead of prepending it is just overwriting the names from the start. According to this (https://www.computerhope.com/renamehl.htm) article that is indeed the intended behavior.

But in this (https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-multiple-files-bulk-windows-10) article they show an example where they are increasing the length of the first part of the filename like this:

```
ren nyc_*.* newYork_*.*
```

So that seems to be similar to what I want to do, but when I try that exact example it does **not** work like that. Again, it just overwrites the first part the name without adding anything, and then I end up with `nyc_(1).jpg` becoming `newYork_.jpg` (the unique number is overwritten).

Is the second article plain wrong? How *do* I simply prepend something to a bunch of files with a batch line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to knock up a temporary batch file to do your renaming.
First, dump your directory to a text file with formatting turned off:

```
dir *.txt /B > list.bat
```

Open it in Notepad and then copy that bare listing into the likes of Excel (or if you have a text editor with powerful features you can use it.) You can then create a formula, like:

```
="rename " & A1 & " 1_" & A1
```

Which will build you a list of individual rename commands changing each file one at a time, like this:

```
A         B
aaa.txt   rename aaa.txt 1_aaa.txt
bbb.txt   rename bbb.txt 1_bbb.txt
ccc.txt   rename ccc.txt 1_ccc.txt
```

Copy that new column back into notepad and save it.
Run and discard your new batchfile and everything will be renamed over.

For your nyc to NewYork, you need a bit more work...

```
="rename " & A1 & " NewYork" & MID(A1,4,99)
```

...will strip the left three characters from the name replace them to give you:

```
rename nyc_(1).jpg NewYork_(1).jpg
```

Comment: This is not the elegant solution I was hoping for, but it certainly works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

forfiles /m *.txt /C "cmd /c rename @file 1_@file"

Comment: How sad. This looks like it might be a much more elegant solution, but gives and impression of carelessly dropped coding noise, because you neglected to an an explanation to highlight the advantages it offers and how and where to use it. And how it works. And maybe an example of output...

Comment: The above command is the DOS command that is needed to answer the question that has been asked >>  How to rename a group of  text files (aaa.txt,bbb.txt, ccc.txt) to be prepended with 1_  giving the requested solution:  1_aaa.txt, 1_bbb.txt, 1_ccc.txt.   Search google for "forfiles" for the syntax to see how it is used for other needs.